# How to create this button with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How would one create the following button using CSS?

[image]

The fact that it is skewed is not the issue. The part I'm not sure about is the diagonal split in color that's positioned from corner to corner. Im not sure how to define a gradient in such a way that it would work for all button dimensions responsively.

I have the following so far, for a skewed button *without* the diagonal difference in color.

```css
button.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: none;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.btn span {
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" ><span>View Demo</span></button>
```

But I'm sure a lot of that will all have to change.

Comment: check with dev mode ( usually it's hotkey is F12 )
if it's applied, it will not have strikeout

Comment: Did you use the search tool Google? https://ihatetomatoes.net/css3-button-hover-effect-deconstructed/ This was on the first page when searching skewed 2 color button.

Comment: google you say? never heard of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a gradient solution that will work with any size:

```css
button.btn {
  color: white;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #e80027 49%,#d20024 50%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: none;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.btn span {
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" ><span>View Demo</span></button>
<button class="btn" ><span>View Demo Demoooo</span></button>
<button class="btn" ><span>View </span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Gradient CSS generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generato)** to get any sort of gradient backgrounds..

```css
button.btn {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(248, 80, 50, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(248, 80, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 111, 92, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 41, 12, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 47, 23, 1) 71%, rgba(231, 56, 39, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(248, 80, 50, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(241, 111, 92, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(246, 41, 12, 1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(240, 47, 23, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(231, 56, 39, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(248, 80, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 111, 92, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 41, 12, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 47, 23, 1) 71%, rgba(231, 56, 39, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(248, 80, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 111, 92, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 41, 12, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 47, 23, 1) 71%, rgba(231, 56, 39, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(248, 80, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 111, 92, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 41, 12, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 47, 23, 1) 71%, rgba(231, 56, 39, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(248, 80, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(241, 111, 92, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 41, 12, 1) 51%, rgba(240, 47, 23, 1) 71%, rgba(231, 56, 39, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f85032', endColorstr='#e73827', GradientType=1);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: none;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.btn span {
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"><span>View Demo</span></button>
```

Comment: I thought of a gradient solution as well but a gradient is fixed and will not line up corner-to-corner for all buttons widths. I was looking for a general solution for any given button independent of width/inner text

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.btn{
  background-color: #34ADFF;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-68deg, #e80027 50%, #d20024 50%);
  border:0px;
  padding:20px 25px;
  font-size:17px;
  -webkit-transform:skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(-30deg);
    -o-transform:skew(-30deg);
    transform:skew(-30deg);
  color:#fff;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" ><span>View Demo</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button.btn {

    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: none;
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
    cursor: pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(165deg, rgba(245, 80, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(245, 111, 92, 1) 50%, rgba(230, 41, 12, 1) 51%, rgba(230, 47, 23, 1) 71%, rgba(230, 56, 39, 1) 100%);
  
}
button.btn span {

    display: block;
    transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" ><span>View Demo</span></button>
```